# scikit image match_template returns undocumented values

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

The python library, scikit image, has a function called "match_template". It takes an image and a sub-image and returns where the sub image most likely resides in the main image.

It returns this information via a grid of values (each from -1 to 1) representing the likelihood the top right of the needle image is at that location in the haystack image.

For some reason, I'm getting values as high as 3.5 in the output array. No documentation mentions this fact.

Does anyone know what is going on?

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=match_template#skimage.feature.match_template

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to the [implementation of *match_template*](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/689b59a457161b8f3e49119e0b1d805dc038f9d9/skimage/feature/_template.pyx) (please, take a look to the docstring).

They say:

> To speed up calculations, we use summed-area tables (a.k.a. integral images) to
>   quickly calculate sums of image windows inside the loop. This step relies on
>   the following relation:

```
sum{ [I(x, y) - <I>]^2 } = sum{ I^2(x, y) } - [sum{ I(x, y) }]^2 / N_x N_y
```

> (Without this relation, you would need to subtract each image-window mean from
>   the image window *before* squaring.)

So if your image do not fit the above relation, it can be the cause (and you will need to substract each mean).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of scikit-image.

Comment: Seems like the issue reappeared in 2015 - found the corresponding GitHub issue today after observing values larger than one myself: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1712